# get iframe source using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get all iFrame source urls on an html doc. I tried using HtmlAgilityPack with xpath - but I don't seem to be getting a list of sources.

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument myHtml= new HtmlDocument();
myHtml.LoadHtml(htmlString);

foreach (HtmlNode framesrc) in myHtml.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//iframe/src"))
{
    srcCollection.add(framesrc);
}
```

Is my xpath wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this opensource html parser uses query look like following query:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//iframe[@src]");


foreach(var node in nodes){
    HtmlAttribute attr = node.Attributes["src"];
    Console.WriteLine(attr.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`ifarme` has attribute `@src`. So your XPath should be `//iframe/@src`. It will select `@src` of all `iframe`.

Comment: thanks! do you know how do i get the actual src url from the "HtmlNode framesrc"?