# htmlagilitypack scrape all rows

Tags: .net, winforms, html-parsing, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I need to scrape all table rows with class containing "row", within an iframe contained in a web page.

I currently have this code:

```
"//tr[contains(@class, 'row']"
```

but I get an error

> '//tr[contains(@class, 'row']' has an invalid token.

My questions are:

1. How do I get the HTML content of the iframe?
2. What would be the correct XPath expression?

Can someone please help me out?

**EDIT** 
i changed the xpath to

```
"//tr[contains(@class, 'row')]"
```

and i don't get the error, but i get nothing

thanks

Comment: You only show a `(`, not a `)` - maybe there's the problem?

Comment: Since the iFrame is a separate document it needs to be loaded separately.  You could parse the first page for source of the iFrame then load the page to obtain the HTML to parse.

Comment: @HansKesting thanks for your comment, but i change it now, and don't get anything

Comment: I think @Zachary was right. The regex seems ok for scrape all tr with class "row" but you has to do with the html of the iframe source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to get the source of the iFrame and load the page directly to scape the HTML.

1. Use the HTMLAglityPack to find the iframe location

   Read this on how to get the src of the iFrame to scrape: [get i frame source using HtmlAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110331/get-i-frame-source-using-htmlagilitypack)
2. Do a WebRequest to get the src of the iFrame
3. Use HTMLAglityPack to parse the response.