# How to get value of iFrame id

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have a html page,but i can`t get the value of iframe src.
this is my code

```
                string requestUrl = URL.Text;
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                string responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();

                doc.LoadHtml(responseText);

                var content = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//iframe[@class='ifram']//iframe");
                var src= content.Select(x => x.Attributes["src"]);
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to get the contents of an iframe. HtmlAgilityPack does not have a live DOM. That is, you cannot get elements from inside an iframe because it doesn't actually load the contents of the iframe.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110331/get-i-frame-source-using-htmlagilitypack